# Generic Vararg Safety

Tags: java, generics, heap-pollution

I have a function. I like my function. It makes lists and it makes me happy. My IDE gives me a warning about my function though, talking about potential heap pollution. I can add an annotation to suppress this warning, but I want to make sure I'm not suppressing a legitimate concern. Can anyone confirm whether the function below is safe/unsafe?

```
public static <T> List<T> listIt(T... t) {
    List<T> lzt = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T i: t)
        lzt.add(i);
    return lzt;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of describing the diagnostic message, you could actually present the message itself?

Comment: BTW, `return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(t));` is a bit more pithy, and potentially a bit more performant, although it doesn't avoid the issue you ask about.

Comment: Arrays.asList returns a list that isn't modifiable! That's the only problem there..